# Node google api body of email

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I'm using the node googleapi gmail client to send an email with the following code:

```
var email_lines = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "to: ", "thing@gmail.com", "\n",
        "from: ", "thing2@gmail.io", "\n",
        "subject: ", "the subject", "\n\n",
        "this is the best message"
    ].join('');
    var email = base64.encode(email_lines.trim().replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_') );

gmail.users.messages.send({
  userId: "thing@gmail.com",
  resource :{
    raw: email
  },
  media:{
    mimeType: "message/rfc822"
  }
},(err,data,body)=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

The email gets sent but the body of the message shows up in a file that you have to download.  How can I prevent the file attachment and have the text show up in the email itself?

Comment: Could you try without the mimeType in the media object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line:

```
var email = base64.encode(email_lines.trim().replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_') );
```

should actually be:

```
var email = base64.encode(email_lines.trim()).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
```

You need to encode to base64 your mail then do your replacements instead of doing them and then encoding to base64.

Comment: that was it, thanks. do you have any idea why that bug was happening?

Comment: Google API expects URL-safe base64 encoded content but your library does not use the URL-safe alphabet. The characters '+' and '/' used in the standard base64 encoding have special meanings in URLs. Your solution is to encode in base64 and then replace '+' & '/' in the encoded content but your last parenthesis position was not removing these characters from the encoded content so the type of the content was wrong and unknown so put in a file by default.